# Repositioning axes, their arrows and tiks in pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, 3d, axis

I am making a 3D plot using the `pgfplots` package. I have rotated the graph which best shows response curve I wish to depict. However, the position of the axes are not desirable. Furthermore, the text of the pgfplot is not `atkinson` despite calling that package in the preamble.
I would like to change the following in the graph:

1. Reposition the `y` and `z` axes to the left of the graph.
2. Make the plot font `atkinson`.
3. Fix the individual arrows of the axes: Make the `y axis` arrow pointing up `z axis` pointing both ways.

My MWE is given below:

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
 
% Required package
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
 
 
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    view/h=-70,
    view/v=10,
    grid=both,
    xlabel=$I_a$, ylabel=$I_b$, zlabel=$R(s)$,
    colormap={blackwhite}{gray(0cm)=(1); gray(1cm)=(0)},
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={latex-, black},
]
\addplot3[
    surf,
    domain=-5:8,
    domain y=0.5:5,
    opacity = 0.75,
] {1/(1+exp(-(x/y)))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The current outcome looks like this:

[image: Surface]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the font, see this answer regarding how to use a sans serif font for the plot. It is not straight forward, because the numbers of the ticks are in math mode. So you essentially need to replace the math font. For this, however, you can use the `sansmath` package. Since the axis labels contain math as well, they will not use the `atkinson` font.

Regarding the shifting of the axis, this is a bit tricky in 3D plots, because you cannot simply shift the axes along one of the other dimensions (at least to my understanding). Therefore, I would suggest that you shift the plot by 5 on the y-axis and let the axes cross at the origin.

As for the arrow tips of the axes, you can use `x axis line style`, `y axis line style`, and `z axis line style` to individually style the axes.

Apart from the above, I also tried to optimize the placing of the tick labels and axis labels.

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{atkinson}
\usepackage{sansmath}
 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sansmath]
\begin{axis}[
    view/h=-70,
    view/v=10,
    grid=both,
    xlabel=$I_a$, ylabel=$I_b$, zlabel=$R(s)$,
    colormap={blackwhite}{gray(0cm)=(1) gray(1cm)=(0)},
    axis lines=center,
    x axis line style={stealth-},
    y axis line style={-stealth},
    z axis line style={stealth-stealth},
    xlabel style={at={(xticklabel cs:0,-20pt)}, anchor=south east},
    ylabel style={at={(yticklabel cs:0,-20pt)}, anchor=south west},
    zlabel style={at={(zticklabel cs:1,-30pt)}, anchor=west},
    xticklabel style={shift={(-2pt,2pt)}},
    zticklabel style={shift={(-4pt,0pt)}},
]
\addplot3[
    surf,
    domain=-5:8,
    domain y=-0.5:-5,
    opacity=0.75,
] {1/(1+exp(-(x/(y+5.5))))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for solving this. I was struggling with the axes placement.

Comment: @Ginko-Mitten The problem is that when using `axis line shift` together with 3D plots, the shift cannot be done using axis units. The [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) states (on page 278): "Note that this vector
is a combination of the two other axes, so the resulting axis is no longer aligned with grid lines!" Otherwise this would be the right option to shift the axis lines.